# Labelling a marker on a Google Cluster Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With the help of another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177999/marker-cluster-links-with-google-maps) I've got a map working which makes the markers into clickable links.

I also need the markers to have a label of some kind so the user knows where they'll link to (right now, they're just blank pins) but I'm not sure how to modify this code to build that function in.

```
function initMap() {

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 7,
      center: {lat: 53.618939, lng: -2.1602328}
    });

var locations = [
 ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.618939, lng: -2.1601132}],
 ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.61953, lng: -2.1623746}],
 ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.6178993, lng: -2.1601596}],
 ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.5369545, lng: -1.9941523}],
 ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.5380496, lng: -1.9974085}],];

var markers = locations.map(function(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: location[1],
        url: location[0] //Will be different for each marker
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        window.location.href = this.url;
    });
    return marker;
});

// Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

Comment: You mean you want each marker labelled uniquely with a letter or number?

Comment: Like [this example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels)?

Answer (score 0):

To label each marker with a unique letter (at least for up to 26 markers), you can follow [this example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-labels)

```
var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var labelIndex = 0;

var markers = locations.map(function(location) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: location[1],
    label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length], 
    url: location[0] //Will be different for each marker
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    window.location.href = this.url;
  });
  return marker;
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/76dobs7m/)

[image: screen shot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
// In the following example, markers appear when the user clicks on the map.
// Each marker is labeled with a single alphabetical character.
var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var labelIndex = 0;

function initMap() {

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 53.618939,
      lng: -2.1602328
    }
  });

  var locations = [
    ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.618939,lng: -2.1601132}],
    ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.61953,lng: -2.1623746}],
    ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.6178993,lng: -2.1601596}],
    ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.5369545,lng: -1.9941523}],
    ["http://www.google.com", {lat: 53.5380496,lng: -1.9974085}],
  ];


  var markers = locations.map(function(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: location[1],
      label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
      url: location[0] //Will be different for each marker
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      window.location.href = this.url;
    });
    return marker;
  });

  // Add a marker clusterer to manage the markers.
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Geocodezip, I saw that example of labelling in the documentation but wanted something more descriptive than A, B, C etc. Or, since all the markers will be known locations or businesses, could the data which Google already has for that location be shown as it normally would in Google Maps. Sorry - that's just changed the original question!

Comment: What do you want for the label?  Is it supposed to come from the input data?  Which field? (there isn't an obvious one...)

Comment: It was the data= string which I thought could be referenced in some way. Perhaps I'm clutching at straws there... I hoped there would be some way to add a description to the code I have alongside the URL and long/lat info which would display where the marker will link to (eg "Google Homepage"). On the page https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wikis/Libraries.wiki#MarkerWithLabel 'Marker with Label' would be perfect but the links are dead so I can't see any info on how it was supposed to work. Is it possible to implement something like this on a Cluster Map?

Comment: What "data= string"?  I don't see that anywhere in your question. If you include the desired label in the `locations` array, you can certainly use it in your code.

Comment: Part of the URL when you click on a location in Google Maps (eg @53.6243957,-2.1747501,14z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x487bbeab0d589797:0xc53d55739819d57c!8m2!3d53.6361623!4d-2.1837795). Probably not the way to go though, sorry! I'll add a label to my locations array and see if I can get any more info from the Google Documentation for labelling to get it showing as in the 'Marker with Label' example. Thanks for your help.